# StringBuffer - String index out of range

Tags: java

the following Code should reverse an String in like hans->snah

```
StringBuffer hilfsbuffer = new StringBuffer(1);

for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length()/2; i++) {
  hilfsbuffer.setCharAt(0, buffer.charAt(i)); //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
  buffer.setCharAt(i, buffer.charAt(buffer.length()-1-i));
  buffer.setCharAt(buffer.length()-1-i, hilfsbuffer.charAt(0)); //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
}
```

In the Comments you can see the Error.

Please ask for more details if needed.

Comment: Please post an SSCCE.

Comment: What is `buffer`?  This code doesn't compile.

Comment: Why not use a `char` instead of a `new StringBuffer(1)`?

Comment: Sorry, I had no time to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use StringBuffer.reverse() method to reverse the string thereby avoiding the loop and errors.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that when you create a `StringBuffer` like so:

```
StringBuffer hilfsbuffer = new StringBuffer(1);
```

the buffer itself has capacity 1, but the underlying `String` is still empty. Thus, when you try something like this:

```
hilfsbuffer.setCharAt(0, buffer.charAt(i));
```

0 is out of range, and you get your `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

From the docs:

> StringBuffer(int capacity)
>
> Constructs a string buffer with no characters in it and the specified initial capacity.

Comment: That being said, if all you're trying to do is reverse a string, the other answers are right, `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` already have `reverse()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. **StringBuilder** can reverse it for you.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("hans");
sb.reverse();
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Edit:

As has been pointed out, **StringBuffer** also provides a **reverse()** method.